# How to make a partition structure

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Let's start with the segment [0, 10] stored in a list

```
[ [0, 10] ]
```

I received a set of ranges

```
[1,6]   
[5, 8]
```

to partition the segment into the list

```
[ [0,1], [1,5], [5,6], [6, 8], [8, 10] ]
```

What will be a good data-structure/way to do that in python?

I don't know the terminology for this kind of task, so my google search are fruitless.

I could always brute force with `numpy.searchsorted`, but this will not be clean.
Especially that each sub-segment is in fact an object with a lot of properties.
And, I have several round of

```
creating sub-segment object / receiving ranges for further partitioning
```

Comment: you have probably a typo, after [5,6] you have [5,8] instead of [6,8]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you'd like to query your data structure or what "properties" each segment has but given your example, a sorted set data structure would suffice. If we flatten your lists then we have:

```
initial = [0, 10]
...
final = [0, 1, 5, 6, 8, 10]
```

And we can transform final into your segments with:

```
segments = [final[pos:pos+1] for pos in xrange(len(final) - 1)]
```

So with each additional segment we combine that with something like:

```
next_iter = sorted(set(prev_iter + segment))
```

This would become expensive for large lists but there are data types that can help. A sorted set container maintains its elements as a set in sorted order. The [sortedcontainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) module provides a [SortedSet](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedset.html) data type for exactly this purpose:

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedSet

segments = SortedSet([0, 10])

def add_segment(start, end):
    segments.add(start)
    segments.add(end)

add_segment(1, 6)
add_segment(5, 8)

print segments
# SortedSet([0, 1, 5, 6, 8, 10])
```

A SortedSet supports fast indexing and bisecting so you can query like so:

```
print segments[2]
# 5

pos = segments.bisect(7)
print [segments[pos - 1], segments[pos]]
# [6, 8]
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me like something you could generalize into a sorting problem. Insert the initial range into an array, then insert all other values as well. Sort the array, then split it into pairs, this gives you your sub ranges. You could set a min/max as well using the first range for validation.